# Problem with updating Discord.PY code to latest version

Tags: python, discord.py

Little background: I'm tring to update embed with reactions moving (`discord.py`).

I got code from here, but this need to be updated to latest version.

Some part I updated yet, but I have problem with reaction detecting.

```
@commands.command()
async def embedpages(self, ctx):
  page1=discord.Embed(
      title='Page 1/3',
      description='Description',
      colour=discord.Colour.orange()
  )
  page2=discord.Embed(
      title='Page 2/3',
      description='Description',
      colour=discord.Colour.orange()
  )
  page3=discord.Embed(
      title='Page 3/3',
      description='Description',
      colour=discord.Colour.orange()
  )

  pages=[page1,page2,page3]

  message = await ctx.send(embed=page1)

  await ctx.message.add_reaction('\u23ee')
  await ctx.message.add_reaction('\u25c0')
  await ctx.message.add_reaction('\u25b6')
  await ctx.message.add_reaction('\u23ed')

  i=0
  emoji=''

  while True:
      if emoji=='\u23ee':
          i=0
          await self.bot.edit_message(message,embed=pages[i])
      if emoji=='\u25c0':
          if i>0:
              i-=1
              await self.bot.edit_message(message,embed=pages[i])
      if emoji=='\u25b6':
          if i<2:
              i+=1
              await self.bot.edit_message(message,embed=pages[i])
      if emoji=='\u23ed':
          i=2
          await self.bot.edit_message(message,embed=pages[i])

      res = await self.bot.wait_for_reaction(message=message,timeout=30) #Need help
      if res==None:
          break
      if str(res[1])!='MyBot#1111':
          emoji=str(res[0].emoji)
          await self.bot.remove_reaction(message,res[0].emoji,res[1])

  await self.bot.clear_reactions(message)
```

Just i want to update my bot to latese `Discord.py`

Comment: And one more thing: All reactions goes to **my** message, but should go to **bot** message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of all the changes: 
*(mine **isn't** inside a class and `bot` represents `self.bot`)*

- `@commands.command()` takes no `self` because i don't use a class
- to add a reaction to the bot's message you need to use the before declared variable `message` instead of `ctx.message`
- I changed the `while` loop because I used `wait_for()`. I added the explanation inside the code as an comment

  ---

```python
    @commands.command()
    async def embedpages(ctx):
       page1 = discord.Embed(
           title='Page 1/3',
           description='Description',
           colour=discord.Colour.orange()
       )
       page2 = discord.Embed(
           title='Page 2/3',
           description='Description',
           colour=discord.Colour.orange()
       )
       page3 = discord.Embed(
           title='Page 3/3',
           description='Description',
           colour=discord.Colour.orange()
       )

       pages = [page1, page2, page3]
       message = await ctx.send(embed=page1)

       await message.add_reaction('\u23ee')
       await message.add_reaction('\u25c0')
       await message.add_reaction('\u25b6')
       await message.add_reaction('\u23ed')

       i = 0
       emoji = ''

       while True:
           try:
               reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0) # Gets the reaction and the user with a timeout of 30 seconds + new Syntax

               if user == ctx.author: # Test if the user is the author
                   emoji = str(reaction.emoji)

                   if emoji == '\u23ee':
                       i = 0
                       await message.edit(embed=pages[i]) # New Syntax

                   elif emoji == '\u25c0':
                       if i > 0:
                           i -= 1
                           await message.edit(embed=pages[i]) # New Syntax

                   elif emoji == '\u25b6':
                       if i < 2:
                           i += 1
                           await message.edit(embed=pages[i]) # New Syntax

                   elif emoji == '\u23ed':
                       i = 2
                       await message.edit(embed=pages[i]) # New Syntax

               if client.user != user: # Test if it isn't the bot
                   await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user) # Removes reaction from a "stranger" or from the author + new Syntax

           except asyncio.TimeoutError: # Handles Timeout
               break

       await message.clear_reactions()` # In the end, all reactions get deleted + new Syntax
```

---

> [Link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to the Docs